# how to manage space between growing parameter fields in Crystal reports?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

In a Crystal report I am passing two text strings from C# application. Both parameters are text string paragraphs basically which can have any no of words in them.

The issue is I am not able to manage spacing between both paragraphcs. As they are dynamic I can't fix their hieghts. If there is more text passed one top paragraphc over laps the bottom paragraph but if there is less text in top paragraph report shows big area as empty space.

What ever the amount of text may be, the requriement is paragrachs should have constant space between them (two line breaks). Please guide me how I can manage it.

Thanks

Comment: have you used can grow property?

Comment: @Asif Yes, I have checked it in both fields

Comment: can you use one parameter instead of two parameter and bring the two string in one parameter ?

Comment: Add the parameter to a text feild and give can grow true to the text feild object.

Answer (score 2):

Put these fields in different subsections.

Answer (score 1):

Put those Parameteres inside a **Text Object** and then set **Can Grow** property of the Text Object as True.
Try this and get back with your results.